# Can't get value of Float field in Solr XsltResponseWriter

Tags: xslt, solr, xslt-2.0, solr4

I am working on Solr to get some data in XML format as explained here.

I am using XSLT 2.0 and Solr 4.0.

For Price field, which is a float field as configured in Solr Schema.. I didn't get the value in XSLT. When I change field type from float to string, it works fine.

I have tried like this... which doesn't work...

```
<price><xsl:value-of select="format-number("@name=Price", '#.0000###)"/></price>
```

Any idea, how to get it to work?

Comment: A proper XSLT syntax is `format-number(*[@name = 'Price'], '#.0000###')`, which would read out the child element of the context node which has an attribute `name="Price"` and format it with the `format-number` function, using `#.0000###` as the format string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code this will give result in string format.

```
<xsl:variable name="Price" select="format-number(*[@name = 'Price'], '#.0000###')"/>
```

You can convert price value string to integer in XSLT.

```
<xsl:variable name="PriceStringToInt" select="number($Price)"/>
```